# How to communicate between computer and smartphone over wifi

Tags: android, wifi, localhost

First, my goal is to access from chrome on my HTC one X, to my local server on my laptop.
The local server works (wamp), and runs from 127.0.0.1.

I can't depend on outer network, thus I want to create a local wifi network.

Currently I turned on Wi-Fi Hotspot on my phone. The laptop successfully connected to the network, and phone actually recognized it.

The IP of the laptop is 192.168.1.150 (I found this both from the laptop and the phone).

My problem is that in the computer, when I try to access 192.168.1.150:80 I get 403 Forbidden, and I get nothing on my phone (I even tried to send packets with no success).

Comment: That's because you clearly say your server (laptop) is bound to the localhost interface, and that means only applications on your laptop can access the server. You need to make the server software listen on the LAN adapter.

Comment: can you share your code plz??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the solution!

http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/how-to-access-localhost-on-android-over-wifi/

This tutorial explained each and every problem I had (how to fix 403 error and open the relevant port in the firewall).